# Will being debtor to a German company affect my issuance of Schengen tourist visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, tourist-visas, schengen-visas

I run a proprietorship company in India. In 2016, we tried to participate in an American exhibition which was conducted by a German company. We paid 2 lakhs rupees as advance to participate in the exhibition; we agreed to pay the balance 2 lakhs rupees 1 week before the exhibition. Unfortunately, my US visa was refused twice by the American consulate in Chennai. So I initiated the cancellation process with the German company, which they refused to do because of late initiation. Now, they are asking for the money through an Indian debt collection company. They're saying that, if we owe any money to any European company, our visa may get refused because of that reason. Is that true?

Comment: Are they doing anything in court?

Comment: I am not sure about in India, but in Brazil, the orientation when you will get a US Visa is that you do not buy tickets or book any hotel before to get it. So, I believe you need to talk to the Company

Comment: Just a note for fellow non-Indian-English speakers- 1 lakh rupees = 100,000 INR, so 2 lakhs rupees is 3,100 USD or 2,750 EUR, as of this writing.

Comment: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3159/should-we-normalize-lakh-to-decimal-units-to-make-it-better-understood

Comment: Did the company file suit against you through the German justice system and does it have a judgment there against you/your company?

Comment: No as of now I hope, because the debt collection company is trying to finish it amicably. They are still trying to collect money from me..thanks for the concern

Comment: Important that you should take any advice here with a 'I AM NOT A LAWYER' disclaimer. The dispute that you have with the German company is a civil case, and probably directed towards your company rather than you specifically. I doubt any European country would deny you a visa on the basis of an ongoing civil case, but lawyer disclaimer still applies.

Answer (score 2):

It's not likely that a unpaid debt, now in collections, would be the sole reason for a visa refusal. However, rather than asking strangers on the internet, you might want to engage an attorney for legal guidance.